# how to POST contents of JSON file to RESTFUL API with Python using requests module

Tags: python, json, api, rest, post

Okay, I give up.  I am trying to post the contents of a file that contains JSON.  The contents of the file look like this:

---

```
{
     "id”:99999999,
     "orders":[
     {
             "ID”:8383838383,
             "amount":0,
             "slotID":36972026
     },
     {
             "ID”:2929292929,
             "amount":0,
             "slotID":36972026
     },
     {
             "ID”:4747474747,
             "amount":0,
             "slotID":36972026
     }]
}
```

---

Here's the code which is probably way off the mark:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests
import json

files = {'file': open(‘example.json’, 'rb')}
headers = {'Authorization' : ‘(some auth code)’, 'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}

r = requests.post('https://api.example.com/api/dir/v1/accounts/9999999/orders', files=files, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should work, but it's meant for very large files.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.example.com/api/dir/v1/accounts/9999999/orders'
headers = {'Authorization' : ‘(some auth code)’, 'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=open('example.json', 'rb'), headers=headers)
```

If you want to send a smaller file, send it as a string.

```
contents = open('example.json', 'rb').read()
r = requests.post(url, data=contents, headers=headers)
```

Comment: what should i mention here in (Some Auth Code) ?

Comment: Here, headers = {'Authorization' : ‘(some auth code)’ ........}

‘(some auth code)’ should be replaced by 
'auth = ('username','password')'
is that correct ?

Comment: More likely '(some auth code)' = '(username, password)'. But I'm not actually sure how he's authenticating with his server. It's probably easier to pass that stuff as a keyword argument in the requests.post call, as in the docs: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Answer (score 3):

First of all your json file does not contain valid json. as in,`"id”`-here the closing quotation mark is different than the opening quotation mark. And other ID fields have the same error. Make it like this `"id"`.

now you can do it like this,

```
import requests
import json
with open('example.json') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

headers = {'Authorization' : ‘(some auth code)’, 'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}

r = requests.post('https://api.example.com/api/dir/v1/accounts/9999999/orders', data=json.dumps(json_data), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Not sure why about the quotation marks.  They're fine in the file but when I copied and pasted to this question, they came out as above.  In any event, the code did not work for me, but maybe for someone else.  Python 3 may have something to do with it?

Comment: this is exacty fricky trick to post content of JSON file to API :D -  data=json.dumps(json_data).  If not dump got parser error

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON, and pass that the body like so:

```
import requests
import json
json_data = None

with open('example.json') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)

auth=('token', 'example')

r = requests.post('https://api.example.com/api/dir/v1/accounts/9999999/orders', json=json_data, auth=auth)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done below code while learning Open API and works fine for me.

```
`
import requests
url="your url"
json_data = {"id":"k123","name":"abc"}
resp = requests.post(url=url,json=json_data)
print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.text)
`
```