# How to post a json file with requests

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests

edit: Apologies, it's been a long day. I thought I had put more info in the description. This is my code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21'
headers = {'Authorization' : ('username', 'password'), 'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=open('tweets.json', 'rb'), headers=headers)
```

This is the error i am receiving, I am in the correct directory and there is 100% a file called tweets.json there.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tweets.json'
```

---

I'm trying to use Requests the Python package to write an API request to IBM Watson. I've been trying for hours and have had no luck.

I've successfully wrote a POST to the api in cURL but I'm really struggling to get it in to python which is the language my application is in.

Could anybody help me translate this cURL request to Requests for python?

```
curl -X POST -u "password:username" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @tone.json "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21"
```

Best,
Ryan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to POST contents of JSON file to RESTFUL API with Python using requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259697/how-to-post-contents-of-json-file-to-restful-api-with-python-using-requests-modu)

Comment: Can you explain what issues you're facing? The [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is fairly straightforward, and you aren't using any abnormal pieces of curl. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, you need to give details explaining what specific problems you are facing.

Comment: This post should answer your question: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259697/>

Comment: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this - you need to grab and load your json data, and you also need to do your auth slightly differently:

```
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/tone-analyzer/api/v3/tone?version=2017-09-21'
headers = {'Accept' : 'application/json', 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}

with open('tweets.json') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))
```

If you JSON file is exceptionally large, you can pass the data as you did in your question, but this is more readable IMO.