# How to Parse Data into a POST request for MRPeasy

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, curl, post

**TLDR**

For my API project I require to send a POST request to MRP to update some of the fields.
What I am currently struggling with is the ability to parse in the parameters as data, every time I send the request I get a code 400.

**Full Explanation**

MRPeasy has a [documentation page](https://www.mrpeasy.com/resources/api/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIkYbzg5DN-AIVTZ7tCh0PdAWrEAAYASAAEgLjvPD_BwE) which I am using heavily for this project as that is the only source of info.
In that article they give 2 examples, 1 for GET and 1 for POST, I have no issues whatsoever with the get request, it works perfectly fine. However, the POST does not, they are as follows:

```
curl -X "GET" "https://app.mrpeasy.com/rest/v1/items" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-H 'access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx'

curl -X "PUT" "https://app.mrpeasy.com/rest/v1/items/5" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-H 'access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-d '{"selling_price": "2.54"}'
```

Below is my representation of the above code in python:

````
```python
url = "https://app.mrpeasy.com/rest/v1/manufacturing-orders/69"
headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "api_key": my_api_key,
            "access_key": my_access_key
           }
print(requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()["custom_3338"])

url = "https://app.mrpeasy.com/rest/v1/manufacturing-orders/69"
headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "api_key": my_api_key,
            "access_key": my_access_key
           }
data = json.dumps({"custom_3338": "1654642800.0000000000"})
print(requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).status_code)
```
````

Regarding the data variable, I have tried all of the below:

```
'{"custom_3338": "1654642800.0000000000"}'
{"custom_3338": "1654642800.0000000000"}
{"due_date": "1654642800.0000000000"}
{"quantity": 3}
'{"quantity": 3}'
```

I hope that is sufficient information. If you need anything else from me, please let me know, I'll be more than happy to provide.

Many Thanks,
Greg

P.S. This is my first post so I apologise if I didn't follow some rules or best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a json File contains the data you want to send as data and send the request with the JSON file itself.

- JSON

```
{"custom_3338": "1654642800.0000000000"}
```

- curl

```
    curl -X POST \
       -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
       -H 'api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
       -H 'access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
       --data "@./processGroup.json" \
       https://app.mrpeasy.com/....
```

Or easier actually, pass the data directly in the body :

```
    curl -X POST \
       -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
       -H 'api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
       -H 'access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
       --data '{"custom_3338": "1654642800.0000000000"}' \
       https://app.mrpeasy.com/....
```

Comment: Hi @Shachar297, Thank you for your reply. Firstly I wish to say that I have forgotten to add in `data = json.dumps({"custom_3338": "1654642800.0000000000"})`, this will turn the dictionary format into json. However, I have tried what you have suggested and I am a little confused. I have saved the data into a json file however, to be able to use the data in said json file I will need to open it and save it to a variable, and that gets be back to square 1.

Comment: Not sure i understand why would you save it into a variable...
You should use a json file on a json format and pass it in as a data.

```

curl -X POST \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -H 'api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
   -H 'access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
   --data "@./myJsonFile.json" \
   https://app.mrpeasy.com/....

```

Comment: I see, I have followed this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259697/how-to-post-contents-of-json-file-to-restful-api-with-python-using-requests-modu) to parse in the file. However, it still gives me error code 400. That is the code that I used: `print(requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=open("data.json", "rb")).status_code)` and this is the data in the json file: {"custom_3338": "1654642800.0000000000"}